# How to read the JSon Object in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a object in a JSON Format and I need to read it and put it in an Object of that class. How to??

```
mainResult = {"metricsId":1161,"metricsName":"Headcount edit","metricsDesc":"Number of employees","createdOn":"Nov 22, 2013 12:00:00 AM","createdBy":"madhuc23@in.ibm.com","lastComputed":"Mar 14, 2014 12:00:00 AM","upadateFrequency":"Weekly"}
```

What I did was..

```
MetricsMaster newmetricsMasterData = json.fromJson(
            metricsMaster, MetricsMaster.class);

    System.out.println("newmetricsMasterData== " + newmetricsMasterData);
```

but got exception saying,

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/SynergyWeb] threw exception [Request processing failed;
nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonParseException:
The JsonDeserializer StringTypeAdapter failed to deserialize json object
  {"metricsName":"Headcount edit","metricsType":"Statistics","metricsId":0,"actulaVariables":[{"variableName":"TotalEmps","criteria":"SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT EMP_NO) from SYNERGYRAWDATA.BLUEPAGE","classification":"info","computeTermType":"Weekly","datasource":"Bluepage","dataSourceType":"DataSource","effectiveDate":"Select","attribute":{"Bluepage.EMP_NO":"Count"},"day":0,"month":0,"week":0}],"actualExpression":{"expression":"TotalEmps"},"normalizedResultExpression":{"expression":"actualValue"},"datasets":["Bluepage"],"dependencyMetrics":[],"computationType":"Weekly"}
given the type class java.lang.String] with root cause
Throwable occurred: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:184)
at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$StringTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:968)
at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$StringTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:960)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:51)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error means that Gson was unable to put a value from the JSON into the Java instance because the Java instance expected a String but the JSON didn't contain a String at that place.

I suggest you write a test case which takes the JSON string and tries to convert that into an instance of `MetricsMaster`.

That way, you can run the code many times in quick succession and modify the JSON input until the error goes away.